# analytic function from the unit disk onto $\{z: \vert z \vert >1\}$ which is not bijection

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Examples of analytic function from the unit disk onto $\{z: \vert z \vert >1\}$ which is not bijection?

Can anyone tell me what should be the line of thought. I think of the function  $1/z$, need help.

Comment: There won't be an analytic function from the disc to your set that is a bijection.

Comment: Your set is the image of the right half-plane under the exponential map.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a bijection from $\{z:|z|<1\}$ to $\{z:\Re z > 0\}$, that is,
$\phi(z) = \frac{1+z}{1-z}$.

Then the function $f(z) = e^{\phi(z)}$ is your desired function.

Comment: So if I can find different $\phi (z)$ then I can generate different $f(z)$?

Comment: Yeah, you are right!